# Does $\sin\vartheta=2^n\sin\frac{\vartheta}{2^n}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}$ imply $\vartheta=1$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry, induction, recurrence-relations, infinite-product

From the formula, $$\sin\vartheta = 2\cos\frac{\vartheta}2\sin\frac{\vartheta}2\tag1$$ by dividing both sides by $\cos\vartheta$ we could derive that $$\tan \vartheta = \frac 2{\cos \vartheta}\cos^2\frac{\vartheta}2\tan\frac{\vartheta}2$$ and hence by iteration through $\tan\vartheta\mapsto\tan\frac{\vartheta}2$ and simplifying, we can show that $(1)$ is a special case $n=1$ of the broader theorem, $$\sin\vartheta=2^n\sin\frac{\vartheta}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}\tag2$$ for a natural number $n\geqslant 1$. When we iterate through $\frac{\sin\vartheta}{\vartheta}\mapsto\cfrac{\sin\frac{\vartheta}{2^n}}{\frac{\vartheta}{2^n}}$, we obtain \begin{align}\frac{\sin\vartheta}{\vartheta}&=\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}\bigg)\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^{k+n}}\bigg)\bigg(\prod_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^{k+2n}}\bigg)\cdots \\ &=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}\tag3\end{align} and this is where I am stuck. By $(3)$, wouldn't $(2)$ imply that $$\eta\sin\frac{\vartheta}{\eta}\stackrel{\eta\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$$ for some $\eta$ (in this case, $\eta=2^n$), which could only mean $\vartheta=1$? This is strange to me because $(2)$ is meant to work for all $\vartheta$ and not just $\vartheta=1$.

Thanks in advance, and apologies for the nonrigorous approach.

Comment: Isn't the limit $\vartheta$?  How to you get $1$?

Comment: @saulspatz The supposed formula I came upon was: $\sin\vartheta=2^n\sin\frac{\vartheta}{2^n}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}$, therefore: $$\cfrac{\sin\vartheta}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}}=2^n\sin\frac{\vartheta}{2^n}\tag{$\alpha$}$$ It has been shown that $$\frac{\sin\vartheta}{\vartheta}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\cos\frac{\vartheta}{2^k}\tag{$\beta$}$$ thus taking the limit of both sides of $(\alpha)$ as $n\to\infty$ we see that the LHS approaches $\frac{\sin\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}=1$.

Comment: @saulspatz oh wait I should get $\cfrac{\sin\vartheta}{\frac{\sin\vartheta}{\vartheta}}$ ah thanks! I stuffed up lmao. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 2):

Set $\xi  = \frac{1}{\eta }$. So that your limit becomes

$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{\eta  \to \infty } \left( {\eta \sin \frac{\vartheta }
{\eta }} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\xi  \to 0} \frac{{\sin \left( {\vartheta \xi } \right)}}
{\xi } = \vartheta \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\xi  \to 0} \frac{{\sin \left( {\vartheta \xi } \right)}}
{{\vartheta \xi }} = \vartheta 
$$

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I realised my mistake earlier. This is useful though in proving $\lim\limits_{\eta\to\infty}\big(\eta\sin\frac{\vartheta}{\eta}\big)=\vartheta$ very elegantly, since $\sin x\approx x$ for small $x$.